# chrome extension Refused to load the script even content_security_policy is set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load the facebook SDK in my chrome extension. And following the doc, I have below setup.

What did I miss?

manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'",
  "name": "some extension",
  ...
}
```

popup:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxx',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.8'
  });
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Getting this:

```
popup.js:31538 Refused to load the script 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
```

Comment: Try reloading the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any errors/typos in your manifest will cause the last valid one to be used instead. Try reloading the extension (rather than the current page) to force an update and display any recent errors.

Comment: It was reloading the extension. Thanks!